# JPQL (JPA) Find Object if list have intersection

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

I have two Classes each of which hold a list of Labels. Now I want to find every object of `ClassA` that holds any item of the list of `ClassB`. Is this possible with JPQL? Or using a single query?

```
public class ClassA {
  private List<Label> labels;
}

public class ClassB {
  private List<Label> labels;
}

@Repository
public interface ClassARepository extends JpaRepository<ClassA, Long> {

  @Query("SELECT c FROM ClassA c WHERE :labels ____ c.labels")
  public List<ClassA> findAllByLabels(@Param("labels") List<Label> labels);

}
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following (I did not try it):

```
SELECT DISTINCT(a) FROM ClassA a, ClassB b INNER JOIN a.labels labelA INNER JOIN b.labels labelB WHERE labelA = labelB
```

Comment: Thanks, but how do I pass in a list of labels or the object holding that list? When I replace "b.labels" with ":labels" I get a validation error.

Comment: Fixed it by passing the id of ClassB and adding a check in the WHERE clause.
SELECT DISTINCT(a) FROM ClassA a, ClassB b INNER JOIN a.labels labelA INNER JOIN b.labels labelB WHERE labelA = labelB AND b.id = :id