# jpa containing query with list

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a table Called Media that has a column "tagList" of type List. I want to search media based on list of input tag. 
I need a method like this.

```
List<Media> findByTagListContaining(<List> inputTagList);
```

This gives error but

```
    List<Media> findByTagListContaining(String inputTag);
```

works fine. How to make first one works. I need partial matching as well for example if any row has tagList ["mentos","bollywood","comedy"]
and inputTagList is ["men","boll"] that row should come in result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JPQL (JPA) Find Object if list have intersection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28831350/jpql-jpa-find-object-if-list-have-intersection)

Comment: This is different. Here I m interested in sub-matching.

Comment: I think you should realize your own logic in searching

Comment: Oops, sorry - I miss it. In this case, I'm afraid, your question don't have solution - at least I've never heard about this case.

Answer (score 0):

> Hello, You can try this.

```
{
 List<String> inputTagList = new ArrayList<String>();
 inputTagList.add("men");
 inputTagList.add("boll");
 findByTagListContaining(inputTagList);
}
```

> call your find By Tag List method

```
List<Media> findByTagListContaining(List<String> inputTagList){

 String inputTagString = "[";

 for(String strTemp : inputTagList){
  //here create you own pattern matching code. Ex:
  inputTagString+= "'" + strTemp + "%'" + ",";
 }

 inputTagString+="%]";
 //And your inputTagString is ready to match you element ["mentos","bollywood","comedy"] 

}
```